# Adding Jquery no conflict code to my current code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really never used jQuery so i need your help guys.
I have a template with a lot of Jquery code. After including AngularJs on my template my slide show breaks from time to time. Friend of my suggested me, that i should try to add `noConflict();` line. Based on the [documentation about noConflict](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) i should create a variable, and append it to my code, but i really don't know how.
This is my jquery code to create slide show.

```
// on document ready
(function($){
    "use strict";

    var globalDfd = $.Deferred();
    $(window).bind('load',function(){
        // after loading all the scripts
        globalDfd.resolve();
    });

    // camera slideshow
        (function(){
            var cs = $('.camera_wrap');
            if(cs.length){
                cs.camera({
                    height: '41%',
                    navigation: true,
                    pagination: true,
                    playPause:false,
                    thumbnails: false,
                    time: 4000,
                    transPeriod : 1000,
                    navigationHover: false,
                    onLoaded: function() {
                        var image = $('.camera_wrap .camera_src > [data-src]'),
                            len = image.length,
                            bullet = $('.camera_wrap .camera_pag_ul > li');
                        if(bullet.find('.custom_thumb').length) return;
                        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                            bullet.eq(i).append('<div class="custom_thumb tr_all_hover"><img src="' + image.eq(i).data('custom-thumb') + '" alt=""></div>');
                        }
                        bullet.on("mouseenter mouseleave",function(){
                            $(this).children('.custom_thumb').toggleClass("active");
                        });
                    }
                });
                cs.find('.camera_prev').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>');
                cs.find('.camera_next').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
            }
        })();

})(jQuery);
```

Can you please provide example, how should this code look like with noConflict function added.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: AngularJS uses jQuery, so there is no reason to use `.noConflict` here (unless you have other libraries that are conflicting with jQuery.)

Comment: So if i understand you right, my only option is to write directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you have gone through the need of using noConflict().
Here is how your code will look like

```
//Define you alias
var your_alias = $.noConflict(true);
(function() {

 var cs = your_alias('.camera_wrap');
 if (cs.length) {
  cs.camera({
   height: '41%',
   navigation: true,
   pagination: true,
   playPause: false,
   thumbnails: false,
   time: 4000,
   transPeriod: 1000,
   navigationHover: false,
   onLoaded: function() {
    var image = your_alias('.camera_wrap .camera_src > [data-src]'),
     len = image.length,
     bullet = your_alias('.camera_wrap .camera_pag_ul > li');
    if (bullet.find('.custom_thumb').length) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     bullet.eq(i).append('<div class="custom_thumb tr_all_hover"><img src="' + image.eq(i).data('custom-thumb') + '" alt=""></div>');
    }
    bullet.on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
     your_alias(this).children('.custom_thumb').toggleClass("active");
    });
   }
  });
  cs.find('.camera_prev').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>');
  cs.find('.camera_next').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
 }
})();
```

Also let me know if you are still facing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery use $ , such some other framework.
To be sure that there is no conflict you could simply replace $ by jQuery

Eg :

$('.camera_wrap') 
becomes
jQuery('.camera_wrap')

Answer (score 1):

The provided code will be able to running well with noConflict.
Because it's already wrapped in a jquery->$ closure